# Electric field due to changing magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

If we consider a magnetic field in a free space which is uniform but changing for example say it is B = Kt î at all points. Now symmetry suggests that electric field produced at all points in a plane parallel to yz plane must be same but that would imply if I take a loop with its plane parallel to yz plane it would have it would have integral of e.dl to be zero but it can’t be zero according to faraday’s law. So is the symmetry wrong and if it is wrong then how would we find electric field?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494426/electric-field-in-a-uniform-time-varying-magnetic-field?rq=1 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494553/electric-field-due-to-changing-uniform-magnetic-field?rq=1